# How to pass the output from kubectl task to next task in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, kubectl, azure-aks

I am using AKS.I am trying to fetch the IP of the service post my deployment through devops so that I can pass on the IP to the API Management for further configuration. right now my task looks like this

```
               - task: Kubernetes@1
                  inputs:
                    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
                    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'string-Conn'
                    namespace: '<appservices>'
                    command: 'get'
                    arguments: 'get services --namespace appservices authsvc --output jsonpath=''{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'''
                    secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                    containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
                  name: 'GetSvc'
```

when I run the command locally I am getting the IP of the loadbalancer. but how can I pass the output from this task to the next task? previously, when I use azure cli scripts, I can pass the vso set variable as part of the script itself like the one below but not sure how will I add the output of this task to a variable.

inlineScript: |

```
$something = (az storage container generate-sas --account-name <container> --name armtemplate --permissions r --expiry $(date -u -d "30 minutes" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ))
                  Write-Host($something) Write-Output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=SasToken;]$something")
```

Comment: instead of using `Kubernetes@1` use `azure cli` task and run `az aks get-cred ..` and later run the command you wish and grab to output using `##vso[task.setvariable variable=SasToken;]$something"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the approach suggested by Amit Baranes since I am not clear on the script execution assignment without variable name. I have used the Azure cli task and ran it. It was successful

```
          - task: AzureCLI@2
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '<Service-Conn>'
                scriptType: 'pscore'
                scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                inlineScript: |
                  az aks get-credentials -n $(clusterName) -g $(clusterRG)
                  $externalIp = (kubectl get -n $(ns) services $(svc) --output jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}' )
                  Write-Host($externalIp) Write-Output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=AKSURL;]$externalIp")
```

Comment: Hi, Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the logging command `##vso[task.setvariable variable=SasToken;]$something"` to [set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

But according to your description, we recommend that you use the [output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) to pass the variable IP. For example, assume we have a task called `MyTask`, which sets an output variable called `MyVar`. We could use outputs in the same job.

```
steps:
- task: MyTask@1  # this step generates the output variable
  name: ProduceVar  # because we're going to depend on it, we need to name the step
- script: echo $(ProduceVar.MyVar) # this step uses the output variable
```